# Is SQL Management Studio required to connect a database to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I can't download SQL Management Studio on my laptop, so I gave up trying. I already have my database (got it from elsewhere) and I cannot connect it to my Visual Studio. It keeps giving me this error...

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

I am wondering if it is a MUST to have SQL Management Studio if I want to connect my databse to the website I created in Visual Studio? I assigned/connected my data source = localhost.

When I downloaded Visual Studio 2010, only 3 files were included in the SQL Server 2008 folder..."SQL Server Configuration Manager", "SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting" and "SQL Server Installation Center".

Comment: What do you mean when you say you already have your database? Do you have a backup file? The database needs to be up and running before you can connect to it.

Comment: @HeadofCatering I created the database in the school's pc but right now I'm trying to connect it to my Visual Studio on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

no you don not need the Business management studio it to connect to databases in VS2010.
you do need Sql Server however.

you can try installing SQL Express (which is free)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to connect to a database already running on another machine, it sounds like you need the native client.

Download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978#SNAC

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

Click All Programs --> choose the Microsoft Server 2008 folder --> Configuration Tools -->  SQL Server Configuration Manager --> SQL Server Services.

Now, make sure that the "State" of the SQL Server is "Running"

Comment: Yes, I've done that. I googled before this and enabled my SQL Server Browser and my TCP/IP.

Comment: In that case, please check this [MSDN] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/2deb9bf5-6dac-425e-b90c-ebb81c00f854)